# Is it possible to allow collapse/ expand in a protected sheet?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Hi I am generating excel through POI and my sheets are are password protected. In the sheet I have some grouped rows.   When I open the generated file in Excel I am not able to use expand collapse buttons because sheet is protected. Is it possible to enable expand/collapse feature in a protected sheet?

Comment: The aim of `apache poi` is creating or changing files in `Excel` format (or some other `MS Office` formats). So collapsing/expanding groups of rows/columns is not what `apache poi` is doing. This is done in `Excel`' s GUI. `Apache poi` could only creating the file so that this is possible even when sheet is protected. So how would you create `Excel` files using `Excel`'s  GUI where `collapsing/expanding groups possible even in protected sheets`? Hint: last grey highlighted are search keywords.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your response. Well I do know that collapsing/expanding is done by Excel GUI. But the presence of POI api like lockFormatCells(),lockInsertRows etc which enables certain features in locked sheets made me wonder perhaps there could be an api to enable collapse/expand as well.

Comment: Have you tried seach keywords [collapsing/expanding groups possible even in protected sheets](https://www.google.com/search?q=collapsing%2Fexpanding+groups+possible+even+in+protected+sheets)? All working examples I found are using VBA for sheet protection. So you would need a template having that VBA already working for sheets which shall be protected. Nothing what I would prefer or suggest. Protection via VBA is no go for me for several reasons.

Comment: Yes I knew that there are VBA solutions for this problem. But unfortunately I cannot use them